# Threads no Java

Tags: java, thread

É primeira vez que estou trabalhando com Threads. Criei duas threads, uma para rodar o gerador de relatórios (iReport) e outra para operar uma barra de progresso (JProgressBar). No entanto, mesmo usando flag, a Thread não é terminada (state - TERMINATED), ou seja, continua no estado RUNNABLE. Vejam:

```
package util;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import visao.TelaRelatorioCadastral;

/**
 *
 * @author JFSJUNIOR
 */
public class ControlaThread{
    private Thread threadBarraProgresso;
    private Thread threadEmissaoRelatorio;
    private final AtomicBoolean rodando = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private JProgressBar progresso;
    private InputStream fluxo;
    private ResultSet dados;
    private TelaRelatorioCadastral tela;
    private Map param;

    public ControlaThread(JProgressBar barraProgresso, 
            InputStream caminho, ResultSet resultados, 
            TelaRelatorioCadastral telaCad, Map paramentros){
        progresso = barraProgresso;
        fluxo = caminho;
        dados = resultados;
        tela = telaCad;
        param = paramentros;
    }

    public void start(){
        threadBarraProgresso = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                rodando.set(true);
                while(progresso.getValue() < 100 && rodando.get()){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                        progresso.setValue(progresso.getValue() + 10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                        System.out.println("ERRO: " + iex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        threadEmissaoRelatorio= new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(rodando.get())
                    GeradorDeRelatorio.gerarRelatorio(fluxo, param, dados, tela);
            }
        });

        threadBarraProgresso.start();
        threadEmissaoRelatorio.start();
    }

    public void stop(){
        rodando.set(false);
        System.out.println("Finalizado");
    }
}
```

Tudo funciona, mas a tela que chama essa classe sempre vem setada com a última opção escolhida (em um JComboBox) e a barra de pregresso vem completada (100%). Como parar as Threads sem usar o depreciado stop(), pois com as flags não está funcionando? Onde estou errando?

Informações adicionais

1 - Verificando o nome das threads no método stop:

```
public void stop(){
        rodando.set(false);
        System.out.println("Finalizado");
        System.out.println("NomeThreadBE: " + threadBarraProgresso.getName());
        System.out.println("NomeThreadER: " + threadEmissaoRelatorio.getName());
}
```

gera:

```
run:
Finalizado
NomeThreadBE: Thread-2
NomeThreadER: Thread-3
```

Aqui o método do botão:

```
private void btnGerarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if(cbxItemRelatorio.getSelectedIndex() != OPCAO_INVALIDA){
            int opcao =  cbxItemRelatorio.getSelectedIndex();
            InputStream stream;
            ResultSet resultSet;
            Connection conexao;
            ControlaThread controle;
            parametros.put("logo", "/img/");
            parametros.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", "/relatorio/");
            terminado = false;

            try{
                switch(opcao){
                    case 1:
                        stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                                "/relatorio/rc_plano_conta.jasper");
                        resultSet = dao.ContaContabil.retornarPlanoContas();
                        conexao = null;

                        construirRelatorio(stream, resultSet, conexao, this);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                                "/relatorio/rc_cliente.jasper");
                        resultSet = null;
                        conexao = ConectaBancoDeDados.getConexao();

                        construirRelatorio(stream, resultSet, conexao, this);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                                "/relatorio/rc_raca.jasper");
                        resultSet = dao.Raca.retornarRelatorioRaca();
                        conexao = null;


                        controle = new ControlaThread(barraProgresso, stream, resultSet, this, parametros);
                        controle.start();
                        controle.stop();
                        break;
                }
            }catch(SQLException sqle){
                System.out.println("ERRO: " + sqle.getMessage());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Relatório não foi gerado. " 
                    + sqle.getMessage());
            }
        }else{
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Opção inválida!");
        }
    }
```

Obs.: Como eu só construí o relatório de raças, estou usando o case 9 para os testes.

===========================================================================

## Código atualizado

Case 9 do botão:

```
case 9:
    stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
            "/relatorio/rc_raca.jasper");
    resultSet = dao.Raca.retornarRelatorioRaca();
    conexao = null;
    construirRelatorio(stream, resultSet, conexao, this);
    break;
```

e o código da classe anterior eu transferi para o método construirRelatório com algumas modificações:

```
private void construirRelatorio(InputStream caminho, ResultSet resultados, 
            Connection conexao, TelaRelatorioCadastral telaCad) 
            throws SQLException{
        final int SONECA = 500;
        final int PERIODO = 10;

        thredRelatorio = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                rodando.set(true);
                if(rodando.get()){
                    if(resultados != null){
                        GeradorDeRelatorio.gerarRelatorio(caminho, parametros,
                            resultados);
                    }
                    if(conexao != null)
                        GeradorDeRelatorio.gerarRelatorio(caminho, parametros,
                            conexao);
                }
                stop();
            }
        });

        threadBarraProgresso = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                rodando.set(true);
                while(barraProgresso.getValue() < 100 && rodando.get()){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(SONECA);
                        barraProgresso.setValue(barraProgresso.getValue() 
                                + PERIODO);

                        descreverProgresso(barraProgresso.getValue());

                    }catch(InterruptedException iex){
                        System.out.println("ERRO: " + iex.getMessage());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                thredRelatorio.start();
                telaCadastro.dispose();
                reconfigurarCampos();
            }
        });
        threadBarraProgresso.start();
    }
```

O método Stop:

```
private void stop(){
        rodando.set(false);

        System.out.println("Finalizado");
        System.out.println("NomeThreadBE: " + threadBarraProgresso.getName());
        System.out.println("NomeThreadER: " + thredRelatorio.getName());

        System.out.println("StatusBE: " + threadBarraProgresso.getState());
        System.out.println("StatusER: " + thredRelatorio.getState());
    }
```

E o método que descreve o progresso:

```
private void descreverProgresso(int progresso){
        if(progresso < 25)
            lblStatus.setText("Reunindo dados...");
        if(progresso > 25 && progresso < 50)
            lblStatus.setText("Obtendo parâmetros...");
        if(progresso > 50 && progresso < 100)
            lblStatus.setText("Construindo o relatório...");
        if(progresso == 100)
            lblStatus.setText("Concluído!");
    }
```

Coloquei o método start() da thread do relatório no fim (depois do while) da thread da barra de progresso para garantir que a thread do relatório só vai ser chamda quando a thread da barra de progresso ter status TERMINATED. Tentei fazer isso usando join, mas fica difícil acertar o 'time' das threads (daí eu teria que colocar o valor da SONECA muito baixo), já que em certas situações o relatório é gerado com a barra de progresso em 20%, 30%, daí a thread da barra entra em WAITING ou TIMED-WAITING. Fiz o teste gerando o relatório sem chamar o método `JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);` para ver se era isso que mantinha a thread em RUNNABLE, mas sem sucesso.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: no contexto atual ai você tem no minimo 3 threads rodando, a principal e mais duas, como que você sabe que a que está como runnable é a que devia ter terminado? outro detalhe, seu thread.sleep ali é 100 milisegundos, se sua progress bar for de um valor de 100, em um segundo ela já completa a partir do momento em que você der start

Comment: Sim, a Thread do main e as dua que criei. Eu faço: threadBarraProgresso.getState(),  threadEmissaoRelatorio.getState(), por exemplo. Além disso eu confirmo threadBarraProgresso.getName(), threadEmissaoRelatorio.getName() ou getID() para saber.

Comment: mas cadê isso no seu exemplo? cadê a chamada do stop?

Comment: Eu coloquei mais detalhes.

Answer (score 0):

Ao meu ver não é que ela está finalizando, é que você não tá tendo tempo de ver ela finalizar, mesmo que você sete o rodando pra false, isso não é automatico, a thread ja esta la dentro do while rodando, vai fazer todo o processo e ao mesmo tempo vem seu print indicando que ela está rodando, se você quiser mesmo ver que o estado terminou, após setar a flag você pode dar um .join() na thread  da barra que você vai ver que de fato ela vai terminar,

```
public void stop(){
        rodando.set(false);
        threadBarraProgresso.join();
        System.out.println("Finalizado");
        System.out.println("NomeThreadBE: " + threadBarraProgresso.getState());
}
```

o fato da barra ja aparecer completa foi como eu expliquei, com uma thread de 100 milisegundos e uma barra de porcentagem 100 em 1 segundo ela ja completa, tenta alterar isso(aumentar o tamanho do thread.sleep por exemplo) que você vai ver ela subindo,

```
while(progresso.getValue() < 100 && rodando.get()){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        progresso.setValue(progresso.getValue() + 10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                        System.out.println("ERRO: " + iex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
```

o problema do combobox ja aparecer selecionado não ta no seu código, é outra coisa totalmente fora do que você postou ai

Comment: Sobre a barra, ela carrega no tempo certo. Fiz com que ela feche (dispose) quando termina de carregar. Porém se eu abri a tela novamente ela vem com os dados (barra carregada) e JCombBox setado com a última opção selecionada. Eu fiz umas modificações e a thread da barra agora está dando TERMINATED, mas a thread do relatório fica RUNNABLE.Fiz um teste chamando apenas um String.out.print no lugar da classe que gera o relatório, mas ela continua vindo como RUNNABLE. Vou usar o Join para ver se resolve nesse caso.

Comment: Eu fiz algumas alterações no código (editei a minha pergunta). Agora a thread da barra de progresso termina, mas a do relatório continua rodando.